# Why do I see so many answers in the Late Answers Review Queue?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, review-queues

Has something just changed with Stackexchange? Why do I see 600+ Answers in the 'Late Answers' Queue?

[image]

Comment: Also, see the GIS chat.

Comment: @AndreSilva Thanks! I'm always late to the chat, since there is no user-friendly way to look at the chat from my phone.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe I used not to consider using Chat from my iPhone, but now I sometimes do, and find it usable.  Are you using iOS or something else?

Comment: @PolyGeo: I'm on android.

Comment: We are back to normal on reviews, thanks everyone getting the review logs cleared.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The explanation is over in the sidebar.

[Can we raise the bar for reputation for late answers to bypass the review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue)

It started at almost 900 this morning so we are getting through them quite quickly.

Comment: Note that regular users are limited to 20 reviews per day. Mods do not have this limitation, so if they wanted to burn through a couple hundred each they could clear it in a day. :)

Comment: @ChrisW I hit some sort of a limit yesterday.  Certainly I did quite a few more than 20, but when I ran out of daily votes, the Late Answer queue became unavailable for me to look at.

Comment: That's weird. It says you did 60ish. I know voting has it's own limits, and that voting is a valid 'review' of late answers, but you can also edit/no action needed without voting so I wouldn't think that would lock you out. I happened to start a bit before the official site day change, so I did like 30 or so before it stopped me since 10 were one day and 20 were the next. Rate limit info at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide/164900#164900

Comment: For me the Late Answers and First Post queues are currently greyed out and say "Daily up/down vote limit reached; come back in 2 hours."  I'm not worried, I felt I had already done enough and it made me focus on something else.

Comment: we are getting the number of reviews down in batches should be back to normal tomorrow.